# df type not permanently changing to int

Tags: python, jupyter

Sorry to be asking a question again but this isn't making sense to me

I'm trying to change the datatype of my column into an int and did the following:

```
df.Age.astype(object).astype(int)
```

this works and it looks like it's changed to an int but then if I do

```
df.Age
```

it is then appearing as an object data type? How I can make the change permanent?

Comment: why `astype(object).astype(int)`? why not `.astype(int)` directly?

Comment: @DeepSpace astype(object).astype is what I had been reading about when trying to work it out

Comment: @drec4s yeah that does, I can see where I went wrong now thanks to the answer from briba

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assign with the serie:

```
df.Age = df.Age.astype(int)
```

Consider also:

```
df["Age"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Age"])
```

Reference: [Change data type of columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-data-type-of-columns-in-pandas)

Comment: Thank you that's got it working, and well the aystype way is what I had been reading online. Never actually seen the to_numeric way